# Name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Style'

Tags: c#, wpf

Because I can know the `KeyTime` only during runtime, and can't do binding there, I build the storyboard in code. It works fine.

Bu I have a problem with the `StopStoryboard`. Whenever the exit trigger occurs, I get:

> Name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Style'.

This is the code I'm using:

```
private static void InjectStorybord(Hourglass originator)
{
    Storyboard sb = GetStoryboard(originator);
    originator.Resources["MainStory"] = sb;

    Binding runningBinding = GetBinding(originator);

    DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger() { Binding = runningBinding, Value = true };

    BeginStoryboard begineStory = new BeginStoryboard() { Storyboard = sb, Name = BEGIN_MAIN_NAME };
    begineStory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, BEGIN_MAIN_NAME);//Trying this to achive x:Name not helping eithre
    trigger.EnterActions.Add(begineStory);
    trigger.ExitActions.Add(new StopStoryboard() { BeginStoryboardName = begineStory.Name });


    Style beginStoryStyle = new Style(typeof(Grid));
    beginStoryStyle.Triggers.Add(trigger);


    originator.layoutRoot.Style = beginStoryStyle;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register the name with the style using the `RegisterName` method

```
Style beginStoryStyle = new Style(typeof(Grid));
beginStoryStyle.RegisterName(BEGIN_MAIN_NAME, begineStory);
beginStoryStyle.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```